# How to get Hello World to work with Spawn-fcgi and php

Tags: php, spawn-fcgi

I am trying to run a spawn-fcgi script for php but I get the below error.

```
spawn-fcgi -n -d /home/ubuntu/workspace/Gold-Lantern/glPixelServer/php/ -s /tmp/nginx9010.socket -u www-data -f /home/ubuntu/workspace/Gold-Lantern/glPixelServer/php/pixel.php
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Gold-Lantern/glPixelServer/php/pixel.php: 1: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Below is the contents of the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First PHP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1: Your first line should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

and make sure the permissions are set to execute (chmod a+x )

Solution #2: Change the launch command to:

```
... -u www-data -f /usr/bin/php /home/ubuntu/workspa...
```

Comment: thannks..I tried your suggestions but now when I run spawn-fcgi it just prints the contents of the pixel.php file to screen.

Comment: In both cases it should show an HTML page (i.e. without `<?php` in it). I'm not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve; running an fcgi server is normally achieved by doing something outlined here: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi/wiki/Basic_Ideas

Comment: I am using runit but its for a pixel sever, just serving am image

Comment: I have no issue with python, just php

Comment: But your php script doesn't "talk" FastCGI :) did you read the link I sent earlier?